# Iterating through an object(s) to display a property

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the "question" from the first entry in my "quiz" object.

```js
const quiz = {
  "0": {
    question: "Who was the lead-developer behind 'Grand Theft Auto V'?",
    answers: [
      "Rockstar Games",
      "Rockstar North",
      "2K Games",
      "Activision"
    ],
    correct: 2,
    clip: "https://giphy.com/embed/l41lXyGaSM2Gko4WA"
  },
  "1": {
    question: "'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim' is part of which genre?",
    answers: [
      "massively multiplayer online role-playing game (MMORPG)",
      "platformer",
      "real-time strategy game (RTS)",
      "role-Playing game (RPG)"
    ],
    correct: 4,
    clip: "https://giphy.com/embed/wG9R3HQ65ofeg"
  }
};

let currentQuestion = 0;

function renderQuestion(currentQuestion) {
  let output = document.getElementById("outputDiv");
  output.innerHTML =
    `<p> ${quiz[currentQuestion].question} </p>`;

}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="outputDiv">
    <script>
      renderQuestion(0);
    </script>
    <!-- <button id="nextQuestion" type="button">Next</button> -->
  </div>
</article>
<script src="Scripts/script.js" />
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: May put `renderQuestion(0);` *after* the script has loaded?

Comment: You're calling the function prior to it being in memory.

Comment: You are trying to call it before it's defined, the script containing that method has not loaded yet. Either move your script to above `<script>renderQuestion(0);</script>` or just move `renderQuestion(0)` to inside your JavaSript file. No need for it to be separate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where you've placed the call of `renderQuestion`, you need to execute that function when the DOM is totally loaded.

To avoid this, an alternative is using the event `DOMContentLoaded`.

```js
const quiz = {
  "0": {
    question: "Who was the lead-developer behind 'Grand Theft Auto V'?",
    answers: [
      "Rockstar Games",
      "Rockstar North",
      "2K Games",
      "Activision"
    ],
    correct: 2,
    clip: "https://giphy.com/embed/l41lXyGaSM2Gko4WA"
  },
  "1": {
    question: "'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim' is part of which genre?",
    answers: [
      "massively multiplayer online role-playing game (MMORPG)",
      "platformer",
      "real-time strategy game (RTS)",
      "role-Playing game (RPG)"
    ],
    correct: 4,
    clip: "https://giphy.com/embed/wG9R3HQ65ofeg"
  }
};

let currentQuestion = 0;

function renderQuestion(currentQuestion) {
  let output = document.getElementById("outputDiv");
  output.innerHTML =
    `<p> ${quiz[currentQuestion].question} </p>`;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
      renderQuestion('0');
    });
  </script>
  <article>
    <div id="outputDiv">
      <!-- <button id="nextQuestion" type="button">Next</button> -->
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
```